# Node.js: cycle trough each BSON document and add it to a new JSON document

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, node.js

I have this in Ruby:

```
@bs = coll.find("headers.from" => { "$regex" => email, "$options" => 'i' }, "date" => {"$gte" => initial_date, "$lte" => initial_date.end_of_day})

        @final = Array.new

        @bs.each do |a|
          puts "dentro do bs.each"
          @final << {  :Email => a['headers']['to'], :At => a['date'], :subject => a['headers']['subject'], :Type => a['headers']['status'], :Message_id => a['headers']['message_id'] }
        end
```

And it works fine. However, I need to do the same in Node.js and I'm stuck.

```
Bucket.find({"headers.from" : "email" }, function (err, docs) {
            // docs.forEach
            var obj = JSON.stringify(docs);
            var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);

            console.log(obj2[0].headers.from);

        });
```

I'm not being able to cycle trough each BSON document and add it to a new JSON document.

The BSON document is coming from a MongoDB database

Answer (score 0):

What are u using to work with Mongodb in node.js?

Do you just want to iterate over a set of results?